# Inequality with two absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, gre-exam

How can you tackle an inequality problem that has two absolute values?

Example is the following

$p + |k| > |p| + k$

and the questions is a quantitative comparison between

A) $p $

B) $k$

The final answer is $p > k$ in all cases.

however when I apply negative for both

$$\begin{align}-p+k&>p-k\\
2k&>2p\\
k&>p\end{align}$$

Comment: Did you try to separate the cases when $p>0$, $p<0$, and same for $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, $$|k| - k > |p| - p.$$ If $k,p \ge 0$ the inequality cannot hold, since both sides are equal to zero. Also $k \ge 0$ and $p<0$ is not a case, since it holds $0>-2p$. Thus, the only  option for $k$ is to be less than zero. Let's check what it holds:

- $k<0 \;\&\;p \ge 0:$

$$-2k > 0, $$
thus in that case $\boxed{k<0\le p.}$

- $k<0 \, \& \, p < 0 :$

$$-2k > -2p\implies k<p,$$
thus in that case $\boxed{k<p<0.}$

---

Notice that $|x| - x = \begin{cases} 0,& x \ge 0\\[2ex] -2x,& x < 0. \end{cases}$